# Is it necessary to study the KPA security for asymmetric encryption algorithms in addition to CPA security?

Tags: public-key, chosen-plaintext-attack, known-plaintext-attack

In a KPA attack model, an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ has access to pairs of messages $(m_i,c_i)$ which are encrypted using some asymmetric algorithm. However, assuming either El-Gamal or RSA algorithms, an adversary $\mathcal{A}$ (can/have) access to the public key. So, $\mathcal{A}$ can encrypt any message of its choice. Which is the scenario in the CPA attack model. Now, my question is that is it necessary, or does it sound, to study the KPA security of an asymmetric encryption algorithm? I believe it does not sound, but as far as I search, I've found nothing related.

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do known-plaintext attacks exist for public key encryption?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5890/do-known-plaintext-attacks-exist-for-public-key-encryption). If the answer does not satisfy you let us know.

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for your comment. That's exactly what I was looking for. :-)